# Google In-App Billing - Error processing purchase [DF-IATPU-08]

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I'm trying to use the static responses feature on the Google Play In App Billing such as the ids "android.test.purchased" or "android.test.canceled", But I always get this answer by google when I try to complete the purchase.

Does someone know how to fix this? Or with what it is related? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the same problem, and found no details on that error code. I would recommend using a live SKU id, but with a test purchase account instead.  Payments are processed successfully (but with no payment, of course)

> "Create license test accounts for authorized users. In the Developer Console, go to Settings > Account details, then in the License Testing section, add the addresses to Gmail accounts with testing access field."

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html